# Unable to generate Allure-results files with Pytest in Mac

Tags: python, macos, selenium-webdriver, pytest, allure

So i got a mac pro with m2 chip
framework is selenium with Python

earlier in windows i was able to generate the report by navigating to the tests folder and running below command in cmd

"pytest -n 3 -v -s --alluredir="E:\selenium-python-framework-master\allure-results" test_homepage.py"

which runs the tests parallely with 3 browsers and also was able to generate results in the folder with the help of --alluredir"E:\selenium-python-framework-master\allure-results"
but now  in mac it says unrecognized argument for "--alluredir="  if i run the same command in terminal

i also did "brew install allure" in the terminal of mac but still when i ran the test by passing "pytest" in terminal it runs the tests but doesnt generate any test results files

i also did "brew install allure" in the terminal of mac but still when i ran the test by passing "pytest" in terminal it runs the tests but doesnt generate any test results files

Answer (score 1):

To be able to generate allure results during tests execution you need to install allure-pytest module for python. So you need to run:

```py
pip install allure-pytest
```

And then you can run `pytest -n 3 -v -s --alluredir="E:\selenium-python-framework-master\allure-results` and the results will be generated.